# Kill another Background Application in android

Tags: android

Problem: I want to kill a background application process.
We call the below methods inside a background thread/services and it's not working.

We have tried a few methods available on net but not succeeding to kill the background process/application.
My Device has a root permisision already.

Code here

1st Method:

```
int value = findPIDbyPackageName("com.google.android.youtube");
 android.os.Process.sendSignal(value, 9);
```

2nd Method:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
 activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses("com.google.android.youtube");
```

3rd Method:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.restartPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
```

4th Method :

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

5th Method : `

```
 List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
    PackageManager pm;
    pm = getPackageManager();
    packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

     ActivityManager mActivityManager =   (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

   for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        if((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)==1)continue;
        if(packageInfo.packageName.equals("mypackage")) continue; // here my package defines your application package entered in manifest
       else if(packageInfo.packageName.equals("third Party application Package Name")) // if you dont have this package name then prefer playstore url of this app to get packagename
 mActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageInfo.packageName);
   }
```

6th
We launched a third party app like youtube, Subway surf from our own android app.
We are using startActivityForResultmethod for launching the app.

launchApp("com.imangi.templerun");

```
protected void launchApp(String packageName) { 
  mIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName); 
  if (mIntent != null) { 
    try { 
      startActivityForResult(mIntent, 101); 
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException err) { 
      Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "App not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); t.show(); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

To close the application, the method finsihActivity(ResposneCode) is available.
But we're not able to use it in service.

Comment: post logcat code......

Comment: @anand : I have not get any error/Exception in logcat. I have already checked it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to kill processes which don't belong to your app. The system will decide when to kill and what to kill when necessary.

App intervention is just to tell the system a message, `Please help me to kill this process, blah blah...`, that's all.

Comment: He got root access, so he can do it, the question is how?

Answer (score 0):

[Process.killProcess()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess%28int%29) should work, this is your method number 4.

Read carefully what it says.

> Kill the process with the given PID. Note that, though this API allows
>   us to request to kill any process based on its PID, **the kernel will
>   still impose standard restrictions on which PIDs you are actually able
>   to kill**. Typically this means only the process running the caller's
>   packages/application and any additional processes created by that app;
>   packages sharing a common UID will also be able to kill each other's
>   processes.

Under root permission you should be able to remove the kernel restrictions, unfortunately I do not know how to do this, I suggest you to search for native solution for that, may be some C codes, there are plenty of them in the net.

Also in your method 1 you been trying to send [SIGNAL_KILL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#SIGNAL_KILL), try sending [SIGNAL_QUIT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#SIGNAL_QUIT)

Comment: @SanjeevBadoni No problem, tell me if it works. Also please read the text in gray in your comment box, just before you start to type ;)